# How to add onItemSelectListener in autocomplete Textview

Tags: android, jquery, autocomplete, onitemselectedlistener

Im trying to add a autocomplete and the set an itemItemSelectListener in that Button clickevent

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,new ArrayList<String>());

   //This is working fine------------------------------------------
    editPhoneNum.setThreshold(1);
    editPhoneNum.setAdapter(adapter);
    editPhoneNum.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    editPhoneNum.setOnItemClickListener(this);
  //---------------------------------------------------------------

AddCont_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
      Counter++;
      AutoCompleteTextView = new AutoCompleteTextView(sentsms.this);
      AutoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);
      AutoCompleteTextView.setOnItemSelectedListener(sentsms.this); //<--This doesn't work
      AutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
        rel_lay.addView(AutoCompleteTextView);

        }
    });
```

how to resolve this problem Thanks guys..!!!!

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("AutocompleteContacts"," Name:" + arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2) + "\n Number:"+ toNumberValue);    
}
```

XMl 
rel_lay is a LinearLayout

```
 <LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/rel_lay"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

<AutoCompleteTextView
android:id="@+id/addCont1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="Enter Frnds Name"
android:text="" >
</AutoCompleteTextView>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This method is not called when item got selected by AutoCompleteTextView

Comment: You have added `setOnClickListener` and not `OnItemClickListener`.

Comment: I hv done debuging and found that the compiler doesn't come in setOnItemSelectedListener method

Comment: you might have custom view with "clickable", remove if any

Comment: why u dot try with a device

Comment: @Sree I hv tried this code with device only

Comment: what you are getting when debugging with device

Comment: @Khawar i don't hv any costom view

Comment: @sree onItemSelected method is not called by AutoCompleteTextView

Comment: why u dot try `setOnItemClickListener`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the autocomplete from the rel_lay from xml file

```
AddCont_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
  Counter++;
  AutoCompleteTextView = new AutoCompleteTextView(sentsms.this);
  AutoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);
  //make unique id for each autocomplete then only you can refer it individually
  AutoCompleteTextView.setId(your_unique_id);
  AutoCompleteTextView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  AutoCompleteTextView.setOnItemSelectedListener(sentsms.this); 
  AutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
  rel_lay.addView(AutoCompleteTextView);

    }
});
```

and do the necessary steps inside the

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
  //TODO Auto-generated method stub
 //do here Whatever is your objective on item click

}
```

Comment: getting exception view already added to layout when i try to again add autocomplete.

Comment: why you are trying to addd the view to rel_lay ? if the autocomplete is from a layout xml no need of this line..

Comment: exception ....The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent.

Comment: I think i hv to do something nasty like addRule in layout param?

Comment: may i know what is rel_lay and what you are achieving by this line rel_lay.addView(....) inside onclick event ?

Comment: AutoCompleteTextView is already inside the same layout ... No need of adding it again programatically. try to run without that line.

Comment: I want to add more than 1 autocomplete bro... that is the requirement

Comment: if you want to add more than one ,you should add autocomplete programatically.. this method wont work for that requirement. remove the autocomplete from layout.. programatically create Autocomplete and  on button click add to layout.

Comment: you can create autocomplete programatcally like this.. AutoCompleteTextView autocompleteTextView = new AutoCompleteTextView(your_context);
autocompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
autocompleteTextView..setThreshold(1);
autocompleteTextView.setLayoutParams(.....)
autocompleteTextView.setOnItemSelectedListener(sentsms.this);